# Unable to log into Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, login

All of the sudden, I am unable to log into Ubuntu. Once I enter my password it goes to a black screen and then goes right back to lightdm for me to login again.

Here are a list of things that I've tried:

- Removed and reinstalled LightDM
- Removed .Xauthority
- Installed [padoka PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa/)
- Switching to a linux kernel 4.4.x and also 4.7.6(which I was running before)
- Uninstalling Steam
- Installing libstdc++

Here are two logs:

- [Xsessions](http://pastebin.com/BUvZJKJ1)
- [Xorg.0.log](http://pastebin.com/rvJs4JzG)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try  `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri`

Comment: @db429 No luck. I tried that and also added --reinstall. Still having the same issue.

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` ?

Comment: @db429 I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: sorry i meant you should try running this command as it checks for available propriatory drivers and installs them

Comment: @db429 Looks like that installed something related to my processor. Unfortunately it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be an issue with the Padoka PPA as of 2016-11-07 (same happened to me, Ubuntu 16.04.1, Padoka PPA, Radeon 380X). I suspect it'll be fixed soon. In the meantime, you can download and install the AMDGPU-PRO driver from http://support.amd.com/en-us/download, or purge the Padoka PPA using: ppa-purge paulo-miguel-dias/mesa

Comment: The was happening prior to installing Padoka PPA. I only installed it to see if that might fix it. As for amdgpu-pro, unfortunately my card isn't supported yet.

Comment: Just because I'd try anything, I decided to purge padoka's PPA, install oibaf's PPA and I was finally able to login!

Answer (score 0):

Set appropriate ownership to .Xauthority and .ICEauthority.

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
chown username:username .ICEauthority
```

Set permission for /tmp

```
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
```

Restart lightdm

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Reboot and login, this should fix your problem

Comment: Unfortunately it's doing the same thing

Comment: Are you using or installed any graphics driver that is not supported by your GPU.

Comment: Not that I know of. I have a R9 270x and I was running the stock open source radeon driver. I switched to padoka's ppa to see if it would fix the issue.

Comment: Radeon R9 series is supported by AMDGPU driver. give it a try.

Comment: Link http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

Comment: The normal R9 270X isn't supported as of yet. I think It's only the R9 M270X.

Comment: I tried anyway. No go. Can't even get to lightdm.